# Aplicação e estrutura MultiTenancy

Tags: mysql, sql-server, entity-framework-6

Aplicações SaaS estão cada vez em alta, reduzindo custos, manutenção, etc.

Sabemos que temos o conceito: MultiTenancy (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479086.aspx)

São eles:

Por Coluna: Colocar uma coluna idCliente em todas as tabelas

Por Schema: Separar clientes por schema, cliente1.contaspagar cliente2.contaspagar cliente123234234.contaspagar etc

Por Banco: Cada cliente com seu banco de dados.

Minha dúvida:

A separação por Coluna, tende ser a mais fácil, entretanto, ao ver de um DBA é muito ruim? se tiver mais de 130 tabelas e cerca de 200 clientes?

E quanto a segurança? Lembrando que o que separa os dados de cada cliente, é um simples "Where" where idcliente = ? Ou como poderia ser feita essa segurança?

E performance? de consultas, inserts,delete

Bancos que serão criados com essa estrutura: Sql Server, MySql (Estrutura gerada com Entity Framework)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Separação por Coluna

### Ponto de Vista do DBA e performance

A alteração irá demandar sempre um índice composto, que é maior e mais lento que o índice baseado em apenas uma coluna.

### Segurança

É a separação mais insegura de todas, sem dúvida, pois todas as operações de seleção e manipulação de registros estão separadas por um condicional.

#### Como resolver?

Há algumas maneiras:

- Todas as operações de banco em cima de Views; Views referenciando apenas uma tabela;
- Manipulando eventos que envolvam o contexto para incluir a chave de cliente sempre que possível;

### Ponto de Vista do Entity Framework

A configuração se torna sempre mais custosa, porque todas as entidades terão duas ou mais chaves. O Scaffold da aplicação se torna mais complicado e ineficaz. As operações tendem a ser mais lentas, porque é uma coluna a mais a ser observada pelo contexto.

Comment: Obrigado Cigano, ainda estou na luta do SaaS com Entity Framework rsrsrs, seria mais fácil criar separado por schema ou banco de dados com o entity framework?

Comment: Acho melhor separar por database. Tudo fica mais simples.

Comment: E quanto a migrations do entity? ele aceita multiplas bases? Lembro-me de você ter me ajudado numa pergunta sobre SPA, que eu ia usar apenas WebApi, acabei desistindo, usarei o MVC do asp.net e só usarei o "SPA" na Home que rendeniza com @renderbody, aí fica mais fácil acessar pelo begin_autentication né

Comment: Você pode escrever um sistema só e abrir vários sites no seu servidor, sendo cada database atendendo um cliente diferente. O EF até aceita múltiplas bases, mas não vejo necessidade de usar vários contextos no início da sua aplicação.

Comment: não quis dizer vários contextos na aplicação, 1 único deploy, aí passa o banco de dados ao usuário se autenticar, só deixar configuravel o contexto, o que acha?

Comment: ISso é possível e bem fácil de fazer. Cada cliente teria o seu database. Ao autenticar, você faz o usuário conectar a um contexto específico.

Comment: Entendi =D obrigado Cigano, nem sei como agradecer kkk obrigado mesmo, logo vou a curitiba fazer um treinamento, te pago uma cerveja lá kkk

Comment: @Rod Moro em São Paulo, cara. Vou pra Curitiba só uma ou duas vezes por mês. No meu perfil tem um link pra você me pagar uma bera, se quiser huahuahaua