# Como implementar o padrão apresentado em C# com EntityFramework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, design-pattern

Estou pensando em uma forma de aplicar o padrão (***[multi-tenant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitenancy)***), levantado nessa questão **([Padrão que contribuiu com a confiabilidade de um software que precisa atender modelos complexos, como modelos multiempresas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/32270/padr%C3%A3o-que-contribuiu-com-a-confiabilidade-de-um-software-que-precisa-atender-mo))**, em uma aplicação ***c#*** com ***EntityFramework***.

Como o título da questão apresenta, o padrão se baseia em uma forma de proteger a aplicação para que dados de uma Revenda, suas empresas clientes e os clientes dela não tenham seus dados apresentados para outros.

> Acredito que o padrão [***multi-tenant***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitenancy) ("multi-inquilino") seria adequado para esse caso - ainda que seja um único operador de uma única empresa a acessar os diversos *tenants*. **[Esse artigo](http://imasters.com.br/artigo/19067/cloud/entendendo-o-modelo-multi-tenancy/)** descreve brevemente a filosofia por trás do *multitenancy*.

É uma aplicação multi-perfíl de acesso.

Então, pensei em fazer isso em uma classe base para os repositórios.
Logo, comecei por criar algo assim:

Uma interface para definir um padrão:

```cs
public interface IRepository<TContext, T, TKey> : IDisposable
    where TContext : DbContext, new()
    where T : class
{
    T Get(TKey id);
    IQueryable<T> GetAll(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter);

    IQueryable<T> Query(params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includes);

    T Add(T entity);
    List<T> AddRange(List<T> items);
    bool Edit(T entity);
    bool Delete(TKey id);
    bool Delete(T entity);
    int Delete(Expression<Func<T, bool>> where);

    int SaveChanges();
}
```

E uma classe abstrata, que implementa essa interface, para ser herdada pelas classes de repositório:

```cs
public abstract class CustomRepository<TContext, T, TKey> : IRepository<TContext, T, TKey>
    where TContext : DbContext, new()
    where T : class
{
    private TContext _context = null;
    private bool _responsibleContext = false;

    /// <summary>
    /// constructor
    /// </summary>
    public CustomRepository()
    {
        _context = new TContext();
        _responsibleContext = true;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// constructor with a DbContext param
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="context">A DbContext param</param>
    public CustomRepository(TContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
        _responsibleContext = false;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// disposer
    /// </summary>
    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (_responsibleContext && _context != null)
            _context.Dispose();
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    #region other interface implementations ...

    public T Get(TKey id)
    {
        return _context.Set<T>().Find(id);
    }

    public IQueryable<T> GetAll(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter)
    {
        return Query().Where(filter);
    }

    public IQueryable<T> Query(params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includes)
    {
        IQueryable<T> set = _context.Set<T>();
        foreach (var include in includes)
            set = set.Include(include);
        return set;
    }

    public T Add(T entity)
    {
        _context.Set<T>().Add(entity);
        SaveChanges();
        return entity;
    }

    public List<T> AddRange(List<T> items)
    {
        _context.Set<T>().AddRange(items);
        SaveChanges();
        return items;
    }

    public bool Edit(T entity)
    {
        var result = false;
        _context.Entry<T>(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
        if (SaveChanges() > 0)
            result = true;
        return result;
    }

    public bool Delete(TKey id)
    {
        var entity = Get(id);
        return Delete(entity);
    }

    public bool Delete(T entity)
    {
        _context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Deleted;
        return SaveChanges() > 0;
    }

    public int Delete(Expression<Func<T, bool>> where)
    {
        var entries = Query().Where(where);
        _context.Set<T>().RemoveRange(entries);
        return SaveChanges();
    }

    public int SaveChanges()
    {
        return _context.SaveChanges();
    }

    #endregion other interface implementations ...
}
```

E se eu entendi bem a proposta do padrão, eu teria que passar uma referência de instância do meu Usuário da sessão, logo eu poderia alterar os métodos para algo como:

```cs
public T Get(TKey id)
{
    var entry = _context.Set<T>().Find(id);
    if (entry.RevendaId == userSession.RevendaId && 
      entry.EmpresaId == userSession.EmpresaId && 
      entry.ClienteId == userSession.ClienteId)
        return entry;
    else
        return null;
}
```

E também:

```cs
public IQueryable<T> Query(params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includes)
{
    IQueryable<T> set = _context.Set<T>();
    foreach (var include in includes)
        set = set.Include(include);

    set = set.Where(x => x.RevendaId == userSession.RevendaId &&
      x.EmpresaId == userSession.EmpresaId &&
      x.ClienteId == userSession.ClienteId);

    return set;
}
```

E aplicar essa abordagem em todos os métodos.

**Bom, tenho duas perguntas**:

1. Essa abordagem na tentativa de implementar o padrão seria uma forma correta?

   1.1. Se não, como seria uma implementação correta desse padrão no cenário apresentado?
2. Se sim, como eu passaria uma instância do Usuário da Sessão para a instância do repositório?

Comment: pra piorar sua situação, ainda existe as autorização, que cada usuário terá certas autorizações por empresa kkk é bem complexo isso, vou acompanhar as respostas

Comment: Vocês gostam dessa tranqueira de repositório, né? Eita, vida.

Comment: @TiagoSilva Vou responder sua pergunta, mas antes vou te recomendar [essa leitura aqui](http://ayende.com/blog/3955/repository-is-the-new-singleton) do criador do Entity Framework. Aí acho que vai ficar mais claro do porquê do repositório com EF ser uma bugiganga.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez: acho que você fez uma pequena confusão... o Entity Framework é da Microsoft. O Ayende é o cara do NHibernate.

Comment: @MiguelAngelo Eu não. [Esse cara aqui](http://www.nogginbox.co.uk/blog/do-we-need-the-repository-pattern), então.

Comment: Ah tá... o site se refere a um Profiler do Entity Framework, feito pelo Ayende.

Comment: Esse Ayende é o *Dick of The Galaxies*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O que você está chamando de repositório não é bem o *padrão de repositório*, pois você está deixando vazar o IQueryable... mas não quero entrar em muitos detalhes sobre nomenclatura, pois isso seria muito purismo. Dito isso, vou continuar a me referir ao padrão descrito por você como repositório.

### O que me parece ser seu objetivo é:

- criar um componente encapsulado, que possa ser reutilizado
- aplicar filtros em todas as queries, de forma a impossibilitar que usuários de um inquilino A efetuem operações sobre dados de outro inquilino B
- passar o usuário logado como parâmetro deste componente, e usar essas informações no filtro (ou seja, o usuário logado está associado a um inquilino específico)

### Minhas sugestões para atingir seu objetivo:

- **usar injeção de dependências** para injetar a interface `IRepository<T>` seja lá onde for que você queira (seus dependentes). Exemplo:

  ```
  class EuDependoDeUmRepositorio
  {
      IRepository<MinhaEntidade> repositorio;
      public EuDependoDeUmRepositorio(IRepository<MinhaEntidade> repositorio)
      {
          this.repositorio = repositorio;
      }

      public void FazerAlgumaCoisa()
      {
          // operações sobre `this.repositorio`
      }
  }
  ```
- fazer uma **implementação genérica de `IRepository<T>`** dependente de uma interface que represente o usuário logado, que será injetado nele... exemplo `ISessaoUsuario`

  ```
  class Repository<T> : IRepository<T>
  {
      ISessaoUsuario sessaoUsuario;
      public Repository(ISessaoUsuario sessaoUsuario)
      {
          this.sessaoUsuario = sessaoUsuario;
      }

      // mais detalhes sobre os outros métodos abaixo
  }
  ```
- na implementação concreta do `IRepository<T>`, em todos os métodos de obtenção de dados, usar um **visitador de `Expression<T>` com objetivo de alterar o `IQueryable<T>`** e aplicar os filtros de forma automática, nas propriedades que identificam o inquilino.

  Ou seja, transformar isso:

  ```
  db.MinhaEntidade.Where(e => e.Nome == "xpto")
  ```

  Automaticamente nisso:

  ```
  db.MinhaEntidade.Where(e => e.Nome == "xpto"
      && e.InquilinoId == this.SessaoUsuario.InquilinoId)
  ```

  Manipular objetos `Expression<T>` é a parte mais trabalhosa, mas pense bem, ela é praticamente genérica para qualquer ORM que suporte LINQ... é muito reutilizável, vale a pena.
- ainda nesta implementação, no método de salvamento, obter todas as entidades que serão salvas e **verificar se a entidade está sendo salva no inquilino correto**. Para fazer isso, sugiro que as entidades implementem uma interface do tipo `IInquilinoEspecifico`, que permite obter de forma fácil qual é o inquilino do objeto sendo salvo

  ```
   foreach (var e in entidadesModificadas.OfType<IInquilinoEspecifico>())
   {
       if (e.InquilinoId != this.SessaoUsuario.InquilinoId)
           throw new Exception("Você não pode salvar dados de um inquilino diferente do que o usuário logado");
   }
  ```

Comment: Neste caso, você pode implementar um `IDbSet<T>` ou `IObjectSet<T>`, que recebe `IUsuarioSessao` e seria injetado nos dependentes. Essa implementação ficaria responsável por alterar a `Expression<T>` da interface `IQueryable<T>`, sempre que a mesma estiver prestes a ser materializada, e também por verificar objetos sendo salvos. Dá no mesmo, é como se o `IDbSet<T>` fosse o `IRepository<T>`.

Answer (score 2):

Vou tentar dar uma resposta que não seja opinativa.

## Essa abordagem na tentativa de implementar o padrão seria uma forma correta?

Aparentemente sua arquitetura usa uma base de dados apenas, e cada `query` executada sempre leva em consideração um esquema de chave composta. Há alguns problemas:

- Não está claro como a sessão será passada para dentro do repositório;
- Não está claro como será feita a persistência de dados;
- Algumas coisas estão ainda prolixas, como por exemplo:

  ```
  public bool Edit(T entity)
  {
      var result = false;
      _context.Entry<T>(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
      if (SaveChanges() > 0)
          result = true;
      return result;
  }
  ```

  E que poderia ser simplificado para:

  ```
  public bool Edit(T entity)
  {
      _context.Entry<T>(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
      return SaveChanges() > 0;
  }
  ```

Do ponto de vista do Entity Framework, você está subaproveitando o Framework em favor de uma abordagem pouco flexível, e adicionando um complicador de chaves compostas, cuja configuração é possível de ser feita, mas sobe a complexidade da sua aplicação desnecessariamente.

Aliás, [já respondi isso para o @Rod aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/25745/aplica%C3%A7%C3%A3o-e-estrutura-multitenancy): para organização, isolamento e simplicidade, o ideal é separar **por database**, adicionando um database a mais para registrar empresas e usuários.

## Se sim, como eu passaria uma instância do Usuário da Sessão para a instância do repositório?

É uma dúvida que eu tenho, inclusive. No seu lugar, eu faria no construtor do repositório:

```
public CustomRepository(int RevendaId, int EmpresaId, int ClienteId)
{
    _context = new TContext();
    _responsibleContext = true;
    this.RevendaId = RevendaId;
    this.EmpresaId = EmpresaId;
    this.ClienteId = ClienteId;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Você poderia estudar a possibilidade de separar os bancos por inquilinos. Para um possível *restore* seria muito mais tranquilo.

Eu adotei a seguinte estratégia para uma aplicação que desenvolvi. Uma das opções na hora de saber qual *tenancy* tinha que carregar era pelo domínio do cliente.
No painel de controle do cliente o mesmo deveria fornecer o contrato (id), login e senha para que eu carregasse os dados dele.

No construtor do meu DBContext eu dava um *replace* no XXX.

```
public class KFMAutoXXXContext : DbContext
{
public MyXXXContext(string database) : base(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyXXXContext"].ToString().Replace("XXX", database))
{
}
}
```

Minha *string* de conexão continha esse XXX no nome do DB.

Em meu projeto eu tinha um DB administrativo onde poderia configurar novos contratos, desabilitar inquilinos, emitir faturas, etc.